# Ruby on Rails - Form submitted twice due to Ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

My form submitted twice as below, it was cause by `:remote=>true`.
I need to use ajax to get `plan_id` this value is from javascript.

```
Started POST "/users/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08- 
29 13:31:04 +0900
Processing by Users::SignUpController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=> 
{"deliveries_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"num"=>"1", 
"box_delivery_scheduled_on"=>"", 
"box_delivery_scheduled_range"=>""}}, 
"collects_attributes"=>{"0"=> 
{"box_collect_scheduled_on"=>"", 
"box_collect_scheduled_range"=>""}}, "last_name"=>"", 
"first_name"=>"", "last_name_kana"=>"", 
"first_name_kana"=>"", "birth(1i)"=>"", 
"birth(2i)"=>"", "birth(3i)"=>"", "zipcode"=>"", 
"prefecture"=>"", "address1"=>"", "address2"=>"", 
"building"=>"", "tel"=>"", "email"=>"", 
"email_confirmation"=>"", "credit_cards_attributes"=> 
{"0"=>{"number"=>"", "name"=>"", "exp_month"=>"", 
"exp_year"=>"", "last4"=>""}}, "password"=>" 
[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", 
"login_email"=>"123@gmail.com", "login_password"=>" 
[FILTERED]"}, "plan_id"=>"1"}
Plan Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  `plans`.* FROM `plans` WHERE 
`plans`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `plans`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 
 1
   User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` 
 WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `users`.`email` 
 = '123@gmail.com' ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
   Completed 200 OK in 196ms (Views: 0.2ms | 
 ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)


Started POST "/users/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-29 13:31:04 +0900
Processing by Users::SignUpController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=> 
{"deliveries_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"num"=>"1", 
"box_delivery_scheduled_on"=>"", 
"box_delivery_scheduled_range"=>""}}, 
"collects_attributes"=>{"0"=> 
{"box_collect_scheduled_on"=>"", 
"box_collect_scheduled_range"=>""}}, "last_name"=>"", 
"first_name"=>"", "last_name_kana"=>"", 
"first_name_kana"=>"", "birth(1i)"=>"", 
"birth(2i)"=>"", 
"birth(3i)"=>"", "zipcode"=>"", "prefecture"=>"", 
"address1"=>"", "address2"=>"", "building"=>"", 
"tel"=>"", 
"email"=>"", "email_confirmation"=>"", 
"credit_cards_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"number"=>"", 
"name"=>"", 
"exp_month"=>"", "exp_year"=>"", "last4"=>""}}, 
"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>" 
[FILTERED]", "login_email"=>"123@gmail.com", 
"login_password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"ログインして 
確認へ進む"}
```

It trigger twice, even I've added `remote: true` in the form.

I also checked my `app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee`

```
# = require jquery3                                                                                                                         
# = require jquery_ujs
# = require bootstrap-sprockets
```

And checked `/layouts/application.html.slim`

```
doctype html                                                                                                                                
html
  head
    = render 'layouts/meta_tags'
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'
    = csrf_meta_tags
  body
    = render 'layouts/navbar'
    = render 'shared/flash'
    main.container
      = yield
```

This is my form code

```
= form_for @user, url: users_sign_up_url, remote: true, html: { id: 
'users_sign_up_form' } do |f|                                           
  = render 'plan'              
  = f.fields_for :deliveries do |fd|
  .field                     
    = fd.label :num          
    = fd.select :num, (1..100).map { |n| ["#{n}", n] },{}, { id: 'js- 
    select-num' }
  .field
    = fd.label :box_delivery_scheduled
    = fd.select :box_delivery_scheduled_on, DateJaRange.new(Time.zone.now 
    + 1.day..Time.zone.now + 8.days)                   
    = fd.select: box_delivery_scheduled_range,Delivery.
    box_delivery_scheduled_ranges_i18n.invert
  = f.fields_for :collects do |fc|
  .field
    = fc.label :box_collect_scheduled
    = fc.select :box_collect_scheduled_on, DateJaRange.new(Time.zone.now + 
    3.days..Time.zone.now + 10.days)
    = fc.select :box_collect_scheduled_range,
    Collect.box_collect_scheduled_ranges_i18n.invert
  .row
    = f.label :email                                                                                                                          
    = f.text_field :login_email, as: :email
    p.error= show_errors(f.object, :login_email)
  .row
    = f.label :password          
    = f.password_field :login_password
    p.error= show_errors(f.object, :login_password)
  .row
    = f.submit 'ログインして確認へ進む', class: 'js-sign-up-btn'
```

What is the possible problem to cause these double requests?
I've searched a lot by stackoverflow and tried, but still can't solve the problem.

Comment: Can you update your OP with the form ?

Comment: make sure you don't have this `= javascript_include_tag 'application'` duplicated in any other files/partials.

Comment: I've updated my code. I checked and I only include one javascript_include_tag

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript events bound to the form submit?

Comment: Yes, I did $('body').on 'click', '.js-sign-up-btn to trigger ajax post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending two request for submitting the form, one is when you write remote => true in the form it will make ajax request and again you are binding an ajax request for submitting the form, remove the remote => true from the form_for.

Answer (score 1):

`remote: true` will automagically handle the Ajax request which means your form will be submitted using Ajax and the page won't reload. You should not trigger any other custom Ajax post request in your Javascript code.

If you want a callback to update when the ajax request returns a response you can do that by rendering a js view on the requested resource as shown in this example:

https://blog.codeship.com/unobtrusive-javascript-via-ajax-rails/

Comment: This is a better way of doing it.